# Rest api calls and responses in Angular 4

Tags: angular, rest

I am trying to print the response of a REST api call in a component, but I'm getting 'undefined':

The Service:

```
  getPosts() {
      return this.http.get('http://api.local/posts')
          .map(res=>res.json());
  }

  getMainImage(postId) {
      return this.http.get('http://api.local/image/'+postId)
          .map(res=>res.json());
  }
```

The Component:

```
  constructor(private blogService:BlogService) {
      this.blogService.getPosts().subscribe((posts) => {
          this.posts = posts; //the response of getPosts() api call is stored correctly in posts property.
      });
  }

  getMainImage(postId) {
    this.blogService.getMainImage(postId).subscribe((img) => {
      console.log(img); // logs the api response correctly
      return img; // returns nothing - calling this method returns undefined.
    });
  }
```

Component html:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let post of posts"> <!--works fine, all posts are displayed-->
<p>{{post.title}}</p> <!--works fine-->
<img src="{{getMainImage(post.id)}}"> <!--somehow this throws the browser into a infinite page loading or crashes the browser.-->
```

What I am trying to do is to return the response of the api call in getMainImage() (currently i am getting 'undefined') and to display that response in the component html as the api returns the response (the page loads and gets populated as the responses come in).

Comment: Check your server side API code whether it is returning the expected content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return a result in `subscribe`. That is what it is supposed to do, you can't (should not) return anything from it.

[Documentation for the result of subscribe](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md)

> (Disposable): The source sequence whose subscriptions and unsubscriptions happen on the specified scheduler.

---

#### Fix

You could use an [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) but you would still have to store the observable locally so it is not recreated with every call to that method. Something like this:

```
cachedImageLookups: any = {};
getMainImage(postId) {
  if(!this.cachedImageLookups[postId])
     this.cachedImageLookups[postId] = this.blogService.getMainImage(postId);
  return this.cachedImageLookups[postId];
}
  
<img src="{{ (getMainImage(post.id) | async)?.image_url }}">
```

Comment: Your answer gets me really close, but the response to the api call is a json object. How can I access its properties? I.e. getMainImage() should return { 'image_url': ..., 'vsize': ..., 'hsize': ...}. I would like to access getMainImage().image_url. Thanks.

Comment: try `src=" {{(getMainImage(post.id) | async)?.image_url}}"`